# Debian : -bash: ls: command not found

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, debian, unix

I have a vm to play with linux and wanted to try rbash. I followed a tutorial to make it work. Then I wanted to remove the stuff i've done, and delete a symlink from `/bin/ls` to `/etc/skel/`. But instead of using `unlink` command, I use `rm -r` on `/etc/skel/ls` and deleted the binary Ls from `/bin/` folder (literaly).

Now I've got `-bash: ls: command not found` when I want to use ls command. 
Is there a way to reinstall this default command ? To download the bin ?

Comment: If you boot a live CD in your VM, you can copy whatever you need from the CD image.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what Linux distro you are using.

Typically, you can force reinstall a package, and hence, get back all its files.

For example, in a Debian based system, like Ubuntu, you'll see:

```
dpkg -S /bin/ls
```

"ls" belongs to "coreutils".

Therefore, force reinstall the package:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install coreutils
```

And, your accident will be fixed!

Comment: Hello, thanks you. I saw things about reinstall coreutils, but i thought reinstalling everything would mess with some package configuration... I didn't want to try this before being sure it would not cause me any trouble. I tried what AF1 said : create another vm with debian, and grab the `/bin/ls` binary and it worked. Thanks both of you

Comment: Typically, you're not changing the files that are installed by a package (i.e. most people are not rebuilding binaries from CoreUtils), so force reinstalling the package should be safe.

Copying the binary from another working system is a good approach, but be aware that you can hit binary compatibility problems if you happen to copy a binary of the wrong version (or a binary built for the wrong system!).

Comment: I understand. Thank you. i'll be careful, and if the binary is making trouble i'll reinstall coreutils package.