# Debian 9: bash: ls, cat, command not found after incorrectly modifying PATH

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, debian, path

Most of the commands are no longer working after modifying PATH.

Instead of `PATH=$PATH:/home/z***d/Programs/anki-2.0.50`

it ended this way `export PATH=PATH:/home/z***d/Programs/anki-2.0.50` wasn't able to include the $.

I have tried reinstalling the coreutils by `sudo apt-get --reinstall install coreutils` as suggested  [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1087632/debian-bash-ls-command-not-found).

But sudo is command not found.

So is there any way to "undo" the changes that I previously made?

Comment: btw, im trying to run the anki as executable file to test first before making a system wide installation, avoiding to run sudo makeinstall.

Comment: Where did you make that change?  If it was just in your current shell, you could just exit and all such changes will disappear.  If it was in a shell config file, you can use the full path to your favorite editor to change it back without needing `$PATH`.  I'm surprised that `command` wouldn't work though, I would expect it to be a builtin.

Comment: " If it was just in your current shell, you could just exit and all such changes will disappear. "

Yes. It worked!. I was thinking it will be a permanent change right away.

Answer (score 0):

If it was done in the current shell, then simply restart it. If it was a permanent configuration change you have to revert that. As a temporary workaround you could assign a typical path:

```
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/z***d/Programs/anki-2.0.50
```

Then `grep PATH: ~/.*` to find likely configuration files to edit.

Comment: Thanks  l0b0, restarting solves the problem. I was thinking it will be a permanent change right way.

I'll keep your solution as a future reference.